# Verifying answer to probability question

Tags: probability

This is the question:

$75\%$ of the students enrolled in Eng enjoy the course, $45\%$ have it as their core and $30\%$ fall in both categories. Find the probability that a student selected at random neither enjoys the course nor is it a core for him/her.

This is the solution to it

$x$ is the number of students. Total number of students who enjoy eng and is their core $= 0.75x + 0.45x - 0.3x = 0.9x$ ($0.75$ of students $+ 0.45$ of students - common students)

Probability of students who enjoy eng and have it as their core $= 0.9$

Probability of students who neither enjoy eng and nor have it as their core = $1-0.9 = 0.1$

Is this correct?

Comment: Your calculation is not clear.  Why are you multiplying $.75\times .45$?  You should be adding them.  Your final answer is correct but it doesn't appear to follow from what you have written; at least, I can't follow your reasoning.

Comment: Apologies. That was a typo

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  The probability that a student enjoys engineering *and* has it as their core is $0.30$.  The probability that a student enjoys engineering *or* has it as their core is $0.75 + 0.45 - 0.30 = 0.90$.

Comment: So, my approach is correct right?

Comment: The approach is correct.  The only error I see is that you wrote that the total number of students who enjoy engineering $\color{red}{and}$ have it as their core is $0.90x$.  That *and* should be an *or*.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!